# Explain this shell redirection: uuencode host-file < host-file >encodedfile

Tags: bash

How the below shell redirection works ? Appears to be complicated to understand the order of execution. Any easy explanation ?

```
uuencode host-file  < host-file >encodedfile
```

Comment: diff <(uuencode 1.rkt 1.rkt) <(uuencode 1.rkt < 1.rkt) && echo "Speed thrills but"

Answer (score 5):

`uuencode` is the command. `host-file` is its argument. `< host-file` redirects the file to the standard input of the command. `>encodedfile` redirects output of the command to the file.

Answer (score 3):

When a console program is launched, it opens three standard file descriptors:

0 STDIN
1 STDOUT
2 STDERR

Normally the STDIN filehandle reads from the terminal input (i.e. the keyboard).  But when the `<` redirection is used, input is read from that file instead.  Likewise, STDOUT usually writes to the terminal, but when `>` is used, output is written to that file instead.

STDERR can similarly be redirected by using `2>`.  You might also see STDERR being redirected to the same place as STDOUT by using `2>&1`.

Answer (score 3):

`uuencode host-file  < host-file >encodedfile`

Let's break this down into 4 parts:

1. `uuencode` is the name of the command to run.  The shell searches the PATH environment variable ($PATH) and looks for an executable file named `uuencode` in each directory in the PATH.  In a standard install, this will be `/usr/bin/uuencode`.  The uuencode program takes a binary file and turns it into text in a special format so it can be sent over a network that can't handle non-ascii characters.
2. The first `host-file` is the command line argument to `uuencode`.  The `uuencode` command needs one argument so that it can put the name of the file in the encoded version.  The first line of the encoded file will look something like this:
   `begin 644 host-file`
3. `< host-file` is the shell using a file named `host-file` as standard input (stdin) for the `uuencode` process.  So when `uuencode` reads some bytes of input, instead of coming from your keyboard, they come from that file.
4. `>encodefile` is the shell using a file named `encodedfile` as standard output (stdout).  Thus, when `uuencode` writes some output, instead of going to your screen, it goes to that file.

There is not really an order of execution, since only one command, `uuencode`, is being executed.  If you want technical details, read on.

Behind the scenes, the shell calls `fork()`, then the child process opens the `host-file` file for reading, opens the `encodedfile` file for writing, and calls `exec()`, which replaces the child process (a copy of the shell process) with the `uuencode` process.  The child process then becomes `uuencode`, with the input file descriptor (a way the operating system keeps track of open files) set to that of `host-file` and the output file descriptor set to that of `encodedfile`.